# How to replace 3rd column given that first two column match

Tags: bash, scripting, sed, awk

This is what I am trying to achieve:

file1:

```
test fileb 4578;
test filec 7689;
test filey 9978;
test filez 12300;
```

file2:

```
test fileb 1;
test filec 2;
test filey 3;
```

file1 becomes:

```
test fileb 1;
test filec 2;
test filey 3;
test filez 12300;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
while read f1 f2 f3
do 
  X=$(grep "$f1 $f2" file2)
  if [ -n "$X" ]; then 
    echo "$X"
  else 
    echo "$f1 $f2 $f3"
  fi
done <file1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
% awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2]=$3;next}{if(a[$1,$2])$3=a[$1,$2];print}' file2 file1
test fileb 1;
test filec 2;
test filey 3;
test filez 12300;
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's|\(\S* \S*\).*|/\1/c\\&|' file2 | sed -i -f - file1
```